# When does the Gemara say "שנאמר" vs. "כדכתיב"

Tags: words, talmud-gemara

There are many times when the Gemara uses the word "שנאמר" when it quotes a verse.

Why does it sometimes use the word "כדכתיב" when quoting a verse, and sometimes it says "שנאמר"

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46063

Comment: I would guess earlier texts/Tannaitic/from Israel would predominantly use the Hebrew, while later/Babylonian passages would use the Aramaic.